# Ошибка opencart

Tags: php, opencart, localhost, xampp

Только установил opencart, запустил localhost через XAMPP. Вверху страницы отображается ошибка. Может кто знает в чем проблема и как её пофиксить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Настроить уровень отображения ошибок (error_reporting) на приемлемый. Да, это __плохой совет__, но явно топикстартер не начнет в ядре всё править.

Answer (score 1):

Решил установкой xampp 7 версии вместо 8.

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно: надо установить xampp с версией php 7, т.к. opencart версий 3х не поддерживает php 8, поддерживает версии 4х.